# Unable to download an image

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I am trying to download an image via **request** module in Python.

But unfortunately, the jpg file is not having the picture.

Here is the script :-

```
import requests
import json
import os

re=requests.get("https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/animals/rand")
load=json.loads(re.text)

# Fetching the image link
link=load['image_link']

img=requests.get(link)

#creating the path of the .jpg file
path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),load['name']+'.jpg')

#writing to the .jpg file

with open(path,'wb') as f:
    f.write(img.content)
```

What is the problem with this code? Or, the API has the fault?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out that your original code works fine, It looks like you're missing the `User-Agent` header that is required by Wikimedia, if you print out your image request you should get HTTP 403 status returned by Wikimedia.
There's only need small adjustment by adding a header into your code and everything should work fine.
You can find the Wikimedia issue reference [here](https://lists.wikimedia.org/hyperkitty/list/mediawiki-api@lists.wikimedia.org/message/D5KDXH2JKFBZ76UODX5WKTP62MMHFPXX/)

```
import requests
import json
import os

re=requests.get("https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/animals/rand")
load=json.loads(re.text)

# Fetching the image link
link=load['image_link']
# Add image header required by Wikimedia
img_header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Python3 requests library'
}
img=requests.get(link, headers = img_header)
#creating the path of the .jpg file
path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),load['name']+'.jpg')

#writing to the .jpg file

with open(path,'wb') as f:
    f.write(img.content)
```

Comment: Thank you so much !, but why I have to explicitly mention the User-agent header?
I am very new to requests module, I haven't used the headers parameter any time ago.
Why should I require it in this case?

Comment: Most websites use User-Agent to identify incoming requests to make sure those requests aren't harmful. Your browser also adds its own User-Agent in the request header when you perform a request via a browser like opening a website.

Comment: You can see the following screenshot that I browser a website via Google Chrome, here's the header that I sent to the website https://i.imgur.com/POuADGd.png